# reset the XMPP connection if the page gets refreshed

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, xmppframework

I am trying to create a strophe connection with XMPP using javascript with my ejabberd server , i am able to make a connection when the page loads and able to disconnect when the disconnect button is clicked.

now the problem is ,  the connection is alive and if a user accidently refresh the page , then my javascript is trying to make the connect again , and in response to that i am getting. (its just because the previous connection might be still alive )

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
            <not-authorized/>
    </failure>
</body>
```

and after a while if i refresh the page again then connection will get established successfully, so  how can i reset the connection in case if the page is accidently refreshed so that a user get a seamless connection.

Comment: What authentication mechanism(s) or backend are you using?

Comment: Authentication is implemented in ejabberd so it is DIGEST-MD5
PLAIN

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the connection survive across a page refresh, keep the `jid`, `sid` and `rid` variables, along with any other state you need, in something like sessionStorage. You can then use [`attach()`](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.attach) to resume the XMPP session.

Comment: Well , as my front end is javascript so i dont things i could manage session , all i can do is to pass these attribute in query string i guess but eventually the query string will get larger

Comment: I meant, you could try saving those ids with the HTML5 [localStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) mechanism.

Comment: localStorage will *not* work since it's persisted across tabs/windows. sessionStorage will work, but not before he solves his page reload problems.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you login with the same JID, which is not allowed. You need to set a random resource to your JID to ensure no collisions. So instead of logging the user with JID `user@domain` you should use the JID `user@domain/some_random_resource`.

Also as a matter of principle you can also listen to `onbeforeunload` and disconnect there. This will not work with webkit-based browsers but will work with the rest.

Comment: if i use some random resources then , i wont be able to tack number of online users which on ejabberd as everytime a new user will be created over the server isn't it ?

Comment: No, a new user is not created everytime. A new resource of the same user logs in. Old resources will disconnect automatically after a few seconds, and as I mentioned you can (and should) disconnect them by listening to onbeforeunload.

Comment: But you don't get a SASL error if there's a resource conflict.

Comment: @Zash As I imply, it's an educated guess. If he can login once, but can't login after reloading the page, I *guess* it's because BOSH refuses the second connection on the same JID. BOSH managers do not always provide informative messages. Of course I could be completely wrong, just can't think of anything else.